# In Mexico what is the most common Spanish word for pull-ups, push-ups, and sit-ups?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, méxico, deportes

I asked a native and the person didn't know (probably my fault). 
Answers on usage in other countries are welcome.
I want to know how to say:

**pull-ups,
push-ups,
sit-ups**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Específicamente en México **Pull-ups** es *hacer barra*; **push-ups** son *lagartijas* y **sit-ups** son *abdominales*

Comment: Hacer barra es un verbo. ¿Podrías decir simplemente «ayer hice 30 barras en seguido» en Méjico?

Comment: Opino que, en general, se entendería (no sin exponerse a la mofa) si alguien dice «ayer hice 30 barras...» Sin embargo, en la práctica (en el norte de México) se dice «ayer hice 30 repeticiones en la barra sin parar» o simplemente «ayer hice barra».

Comment: Quiero hacer hincapié en que la forma preferida para denominar  nuestro país es «México». La forma con "j", aunque es aceptada, no es recomendable. http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=M%C3%A9xico

Answer (score 3):

[Pull-ups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_%28exercise%29) are called ["dominadas"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominada). [Push-ups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push-up) I believe are called ["flexiones"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push-up) (o *flexión de codos*). Sit ups may be "[abdominales](http://dle.rae.es/?id=042kBjt)"

Comment: Yes, in Spain we do say _flexiones_ for _push-ups_.